# Get a dropdown menu for categories to display related post in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown

I am new to php and I am using Laravel as a framework I have tried to implement a dropdown menu functionality in the navbar section for each category I could get the dropdown view on each category but do not display the post related to each category

```
<nav class="w-full py-4 border-t border-b bg-gray-100" x-data="{ open: false }">
    <div class="block sm:hidden">
        <a href="#" class="block md:hidden text-base font-bold uppercase text-center flex justify-center items-center" @click="open = !open">
            Topics <i :class="open ? 'fa-chevron-down': 'fa-chevron-up'" class="fas ml-2"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div :class="open ? 'block': 'hidden'" class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="w-full container mx-auto flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center justify-center text-sm font-bold uppercase mt-0 px-6 py-2">
            <a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="hover:bg-gray-400 rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">Home</a>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <div class="relative inline-block text-left" x-data="{ openDropdown: false }">
                    <button @click="openDropdown = !openDropdown" type="button" class="hover:bg-gray-400 rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">
                        {{ $category->title }} <i :class="openDropdown ? 'fa-chevron-up': 'fa-chevron-down'" class="fas ml-2"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div x-show="openDropdown" @click.away="openDropdown = false" class="absolute right-0 w-40 mt-2 origin-top-right bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-lg">
                        <!-- Dropdown content -->
                        @foreach($category->posts as $post)
                            <a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">{{ $post->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                        <!-- Add more links here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach

            <a href="#" class="hover:bg-gray-400 rounded py-2 px-4 mx-2">About us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Is there something I should change in the models structure for it to work. this is an example of what I have in models/category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug'];

    public function posts(): belongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( related: Post::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that  `<a href="{{ route('view', $post) }}"` should be `<a href="{{ route('view', $post->id) }}"`